# keyed (locking) skewers and seat bolts: recommendations?

Tags: wheels, saddle, security, lock, skewer

I know nothing is thief proof, but some systems are more of a deterrent than others.  Looking for recommendations for good systems.  Perhaps more importantly I'd like to hear about systems found to be insecure (i.e. can be broken with a bic pen level of technology).

And, does anyone use a special seat bolt (the one right under the seat that is used to lock fore-aft)?  I know a keyed seat post bolt can be sidestepped simply removing the seat top - is that a common target, just the top of the seat without the post and platform?

Comment: Take a look at these questions. [Here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3846/protecting-quick-release-seats-and-wheels-from-theft) and [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10396/deterrents-against-partial-component-theft/10414#10414)

Comment: I had to read the answers and the links from Kibbee to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several good options for securing your bike, the wheels and the seat and post. I'll give you the links so you can see the different systems and their pricing. The first link covers the seat security you are wanting, and the second link is for other possibilities.

http://www.pinheadcomponents.com/

http://search.aol.com/aol/search?query=Security+locking+systems+for+bicycles&s_it=keyword_rollover

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a very good solution. http://www.pitlock.com/

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange. We prefer that answers on this site be self contained. As such, if you are going to post a link to a solution it is best to give a summary of why that link is helpful and/or what is contained within the link.