# i am 130kg(286lbs) is mtb okay for me?

Tags: mountain-bike, clydesdale

I have [Hero howler single speed 27.5T cycle](https://www.herocycles.com/product/howler-27-5t-v-brake) I am 130kg now. Can I ride this MTB cycle and I won't face any issues?  I am thrilled as the cycle will able to take my weight or not as I am obese so asking here.
Please if you know do let me know.
Note: The cycle is in the new condition and it's **MTB**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find a mountain bike that can handle a heavier (250-260lbs) rider?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9092/how-to-find-a-mountain-bike-that-can-handle-a-heavier-250-260lbs-rider) - and many others on this site. Please use search the the linked question does not provide you and answer (Shopping advice is specifically off topic here, so do not expect an answer regarding the exact model bike you have linked to)

Comment: A single speed for a novice rider is not normally recommended, more so for someone who is also obese, have a look at   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36199/single-speed-vs-multi-speed-bike-purchase/36207#36207

Comment: Hey, The thing is i already own it. So i am thrilled and asked this question. When i talked to company they told rider weight should be 115kg max. But i am 130kg. So i am asking here,

Comment: If you talked to the manufacturer and they gave you a weight limit, that's your answer. Some of the answers on the other question about heavier riders go into quite a bit of detail about what you can expect if you're over the recommended weight limit.

Comment: Thanks, @mattnz I read your recommended first question and got to know the answer. Just today I took a ride and did a ride of 20km. It's too little I know but it gave me confidence. The cycle worked perfectly fine. I don't know why the manufacturing company 110kg. But it worked. Thanks to this community

Comment: @hetalgokani The bike won't spontaneously explode if you weigh 111kg and you ride it. It's just that you run a higher risk of breaking parts and/or the frame compared to what the manufacturer designed the bike for.

Comment: No ride is too little, especially if you're not used to the bike or even cycling at all. It's worth avoiding big hits if you're over the weight they say, or unweighting the saddle to reduce to shock the bike feels. But if you ride an mtb on less severe terrain than it's built for you're already doing that to some extent.

Comment: A "Factor of Safety" is built-in in the design of any engineering project (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_of_safety). If your living room can only take six persons per square meter, for example, it does not mean that if you miscalculate and end up with seven or eight, the floor will go down. But if you have twelve people (FoS = 2), you would indeed be betting on taking the floor down. Here of course it matters greatly whether your guests are dancing, dancing wildly, or, worst of all, dancing wildly in unison. Short version: don't fly with the bike if you've breached its weight limit.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestions. Will take care of all these things while riding.