# Will this Retrospec Siddhartha bike suit my needs?

Tags: road-bike, commuter, fixed-gear, uk

This is my first question on here so please take it easy :)

I will be relocating to Surrey (UK) in 2 weeks due to being offered a new job (as a software developer) and I am thinking of (finally) treating myself to a fixed-gear bike.

I usually drive to work due to the fact that the weather is usually quite rubbish where I currently live (UK - north west), and also due to the fact that I can't get to work all sweaty as I work in an office, but have cycled during the summer on a cheap "fat-tyre" bike and although it was very hard work I loved it.

I love bicycles and I have always wanted a bike that looks cool and that doesn't cost an arm and a leg - those that are +£300 are a no-no so I have come across the [Restrospec Siddhartha](http://www.retrospecbicycles.com/siddhartha-cruiser.html) fixie - however they only sell them in the USA (haven't yet found a UK dealer)

So I have three questions:

1- Will this bike be suitable for someone like myself that will use it to commute to work (around 15 miles roundtrip)  and go for rides whenever I feel like it and at weekends?

2- Do you know anyone selling this bike in the UK?

3- Could you recommend me similar style bikes (fixie) that have clean design and are <£200?

Thanks in advance for your help and advice

Comment: feel free to answer only part of the question if you are unsure about all 3 points

Comment: If you are buying a mass-produced factory bike, and not a custom bike, you basically get what you pay for. There is lots of competition in the industry, and there is little-to-no room  to undercut the other guy. That isn't to say you have to spend $2000 on a bike, but be prepared to spend at least $400 US or closer to $600 US (or your local equivalent) if you want a bike that you will want to ride every day. Around $1000 is probably the top end of what you should spend unless you are competing in races. That may seem like a lot, but in my area, that's only about 12 months worth of bus passes.

Comment: Are you sure you a fixed-gear bike is practical as well as "looking cool"? Does Surrey have hills? I found that my 18 km (11 mile) each-way commute took me just over an hour each way: on city roads (in traffic so stop-and-go), mostly flat with only occasional/minor hills. I used my gears to maximize my speed (lower gear to accelerate, higher gears for top-speed cruising): IMO that would have more difficult, and/or slower, without gears. Also, the bike you're suggesting doesn't have a front-wheel brake. If you can't spend +£300 for a new bike, then a 2nd-hand bike might be worth considering.

Comment: Good call @ChrisW A fixed gear bike without another brake is not only dangerous, but also illegal in most places, including the UK.  Not sure how much the fine is, but a decently equipped bike could start to look quite cheap after a couple fines.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I think both of you have made very valid points. I have always loved the smooth design of a fixie but as you mentioned it would not be very useful in Surrey which by the way has some nice hills. And I guess if I was to buy one with gears I could spend a bit more and maybe go for a MTB (fat tyres I know) and have some fun on the hills as well? It always helps when someone else gives you their point of view and in this case both of you are right. Back to "square 1" for me I think - need to find a decent hybrid or MTB. Will fat tyred MTB make the commute harder?

Comment: @Kibbee It has /a/ brake (a "coaster brake"), but not a front wheel brake. Front wheel brakes brake harder (because the weight lifts off the back wheel when you decelerate, which allows it to skid). Also a coaster brake won't work if the chain breaks.

Comment: which means using my nice and shiny "office" shoes to stop me from killing myself :P

Comment: "Will fat tyred MTB make the commute harder" IMHO the /width/ of the tire make little or no difference except at the top speeds (because at high speeds, but only at high speeds, it's important to be aerodynamic). What does make a big difference is whether the tires are knobbly and/or under-inflated. My hybrid bike wheels are 700x32: I eventually added Marathon Plus touring tires, to avoid getting any flats. People who race would call them "heavy" but IMO they don't have much "rolling resistance" (much less than the knobbly tires on my department-store bike) when inflated at 65 psi.

Comment: @ChrisW thank you for the detailed answer. I had this idea that MTB bikes with fat tyres are hell for commuters and that's why I never even thought looking into them for that reason. Obviously I was wrong and I think I will go online/locally and see what I can get within my budget

Comment: The hybrid that I'm pleased with ([ref](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/2767/1097) and [ref](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/3056/1097)) cost $700, on discount because it was last year's model, without accessories, and without upgraded tires. OTOH it wasn't the  cheapest available, e.g. it has hydraulic disk brakes). It was also, IMO, relatively cheap: only because I could use it year-round, instead of a car or public transport.

Comment: It makes sense. Pay a bit more and get more use out of it.

Comment: You might want to look for a "hybrid" bike, not "MTB". For example, road tires (fat or otherwise) but not off-road tires; and, no suspension (which, is said to be heavy, and to absorb some of your cycling power by bobbing up and down).

Comment: yet another great suggestion. I think I really need to do a bit more research before committing to buying any bike. thank you so much for the advice @ChrisW I am very grateful

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange! This question is not a great fit for our Q/A format. "Shopping" or "Which is Best" questions are generally too broad, garner only opinions, and go out of date quickly. See the [Help Center](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for more information. Better would be the simple question "In an area with [characteristics], what features should I look for in a bike for [riding type] that costs less than [budget]. Search the site since there are many questions like this.

Comment: @ChrisW As per [this article](http://www.theguardian.com/environment/green-living-blog/2010/aug/25/cycling-without-brakes), bikes must have both a front and back brake to be legal in the UK.  The [only exception](http://ukcyclerules.com/2011/05/04/the-rules-of-bike-brakes/) for not having 2 brakes is on children's bikes, or on pennyfarthings and such where the axle is directly connected to the crank arms, without any gearing.

Comment: @Gary.Ray thank you and apologies. Will try to improve question format in future

Comment: That's a single-speed bike, not a fixie. There are people who happily commute commute miles over hills on fixed gear or single speed bikes, but I wouldn't recommend it as a first bike. With a £200 budget, I'd look for second hand bikes, ideally from a local store where you can ask for advice, or eBay or Gumtree etc..

Comment: @armb thank you for your advice - local knowledge is always helpful I guess I will dig around and see what I can find :) once again thanks to everyone for their advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love to surf the internet for the ultimate bike. However, I always end up going to my local friendly bike shop and making my selection with their advice. The ultimate internet bike will not be able to compete with getting the attention of a local mechanic. Most of the local guys will also take pride in the bike that they sold you and give you free service for the small jobs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I couldn't agree more with you however the trouble with the "local shops" is that their prices are ridiculous (at least round where I live) and if they are cheap then that's because the bike is of a make that nobody has ever heard of.