# What is the ideal saddle height?

Tags: saddle

What should be the ideal saddle height of my bike if I'm 5'10" foot and using a 29" flat bar bike?

Comment: This depends on many factors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the correct position for my bicycle seat?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/51/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-position-for-my-bicycle-seat)

Comment: There's no mathematical formula for this. Raise the seat until your knee is almost but not quite fully extended when the pedal is at the bottom of its stroke. That's a good starting point. Adjust in small increments from there.

Comment: Directly underneath your butt is the usual position.

Comment: Finding the correct height is a matter of much trial and a lot of error. With minor adjustments over again after a new saddle, pedals, shoes ...